# How to get value of checked asp checkbox in datalist with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to capture the value of the checked checkbox in a `Datalist` along with the number of checkboxes checked.  I have this code that works for the number of check boxes checked:

```
function CheckboxClicked(arg) {
    checkcount = $(".checked :checked").length
    alert("checkcount = " + checkcount);
    var selectedvalue = $("#<%=Datalist_session.ClientID%> option:selected").val();
    alert("selected value = " + selectedvalue);
};
```

*** update ****

This is the resulting html:

```
            <div class ="options">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class ="pageTitle">
                            <span id="Label_Options">Please Select ~n~ Session(s)</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan ="2">
                            <div style=" overflow:scroll; height:100px;">
                                <table id="DataList_Session" cellspacing="0" style="height:256px;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_0"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_0" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl00$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_0">10/23/2021 - 8:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_1"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_1" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl01$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_1">10:23/2021 - 8:15am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_2"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_2" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl02$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_2">10:23/2021 - 8:30am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_3"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_3" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl03$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_3">10:23/2021 - 8:45am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_4"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_4" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl04$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_4">10:23/2021 - 9:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_5"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_5" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl05$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_5">10:23/2021 - 9:15am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_6"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_6" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl06$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_6">10:23/2021 - 9:30am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_7"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_7" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl07$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_7">10:23/2021 - 9:45am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_8"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_8" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl08$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_8">10:23/2021 - 10:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_9"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_9" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl09$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_9">10:23/2021 - 10:15am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_10"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_10" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl10$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_10">10:23/2021 - 10:30am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_11"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_11" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl11$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_11">10:23/2021 - 10:45am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_12"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_12" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl12$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_12">10:23/2021 - 11:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_13"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_13" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl13$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_13">10:30/2021 - 8:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_14"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_14" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl14$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_14">10:30/2021 - 8:15am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_15"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_15" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl15$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_15">10:30/2021 - 8:30am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_16"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_16" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl16$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_16">10:30/2021 - 8:45am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_17"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_17" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl17$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_17">10:30/2021 - 9:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_18"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_18" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl18$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_18">10:30/2021 - 9:15am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_19"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_19" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl19$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_19">10:30/2021 - 9:30am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_20"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_20" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl20$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_20">10:30/2021 - 9:45am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_21"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checked">
                                                <input id="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_21" type="checkbox" name="DataList_Session$ctl21$cbDateTime" onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);" /><label for="DataList_Session_cbDateTime_21">10:30/2021 - 10:00am</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table> 
                               </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="DataList_Session_lblHeader_22"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like for your page?

Comment: @Twisty The page displays and functions normally except that I can't figure out how to capture the value of each checked checkbox.  I added the datalist html to my question.

Comment: I see the update. This appears to be the Back-end ASP Code and not the resulting HTML. JavaScript (and jQuery) and Client Side scripting and will work off the resulting HTML that is passed to the client after the page has been requested. To be able to help, need to see what jQuery will be working with.

Comment: @Twisty I updated my question.  The jquery code is all that should be relevant, what the resulting html is doesn't matter.  I need to get the value of each checked (or unchecked) check box.

Comment: @Twisty - I added the resulting HTML to my question

Comment: That is an excessive amount of tables. When I look at this, I do not see `$("#<%=Datalist_session.ClientID%> option:selected")` element. You would not be able to get the Value of this, if it does not exist in the DOM. Also I do not see any `value` attribute configured for the checkboxes.

Comment: @Twisty That's weird, this is the line of code that generates the checkbox `<asp:CheckBox ID="cbDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ScheduleDate")%>' Value='<%# Eval("ScheduleID")%>' onclick="CheckboxClicked(this);"/>`.  I do not understand why the value is not being generated.

Comment: I am not very strong with ASP DataLists, so I do not know why it is not being rendered into the HTML. But if it's not there, then you cannot call the `value`